# Dockerized Create React App doesn't open a new tab

Tags: reactjs, docker, create-react-app

I noticed a strange behavior when running my app with Docker - it doesn't open a new tab.
If I run my app manually with npm/yarn start, tab opens fine.

I **don't** have "BROWSER=none" in .env

Comment: I would assume because there is no browser within the docker container? I have never used that feature, but one of the main points of docker is isolation. So my assumption would be that it has no way of knowing how to open the browser of the host.

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the create-react-app start script tries to open the local browser. Here's one of the relevant parts of the start script:

```
/**
 * Attempts to open the browser with a given URL.
 *
 * On Mac OS X, attempts to reuse an existing Chrome tab via AppleScript.
 *
 * Otherwise, falls back to [open](https://github.com/sindresorhus/open) behavior.
 */
declare function openBrowser(url: string): boolean;
export = openBrowser;
```

However, if your application is running in a docker container, it's like it is running on a separate machine, or VM. Which doesn't have a browser installed.

And the way Docker containers work, they can't just invoke programs of the host machine (without rather complex workarounds).

Comment: Makes sense. I am not sure how, but the custom webpack config we used before switching to CRA was able to open the browser.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting.
Were you starting the docker container via a script back then or was it configured to mount more parts of the host system into the container?

The only options to do this, that I could think of would be:
a) Launch a browser and the docker container with the same script
b) Mount parts of your system into the container, to enable it to launch the browser (<- this can be hacky and would lead to problems on different hosts and host-platforms)

Comment: I think I figured it out. It's not even docker, it's in the sh script that runs docker.


`open http://localhost:$UI_PORT`

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense! It is basically option a.